# Obtener la pocision de un ArrayList de un objeto

Tags: java, arraylist

!Buenas!

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio, y en una de las partes me pide que imprima por consola la posición de un elemento del `ArrayList` que sea igual al nombre que escriba el usuario por teclado.

Tengo una lista de colores, donde solo tiene **nombre** y un **identificador**, y lo he realizado de la siguiente manera:

```
        int pocision = 0; //CONTADOR PARA CONTROLAR LA POCISION DEL ARRAYLIST.

        System.out.print("Dime un color: ");
        nombreColor = sc.nextLine();

        for(Color i:paleta) {

            pocision++;

            if(i.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreColor)) {

                System.out.println("La pocision del color " + i.getNombre() + " es " + pocision);
            }//FIN DEL IF
        } //FIN DEL FOR
```

¿Hay algún método de la clase `ArrayList` que me devuelva directamente la posición? Sin necesidad de utilizar un contador.

Comment: Podrías usar el método `indexOf()` de dicha clase, el cual te devuelve la posición. Ten en cuenta que el valor que pases como argumento debe coincidir en formato con los almacenados en el ArrayList (me refiero a mayúsculas y minúsculas). Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Me ayudo. Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya esta resuelto.

Gracias a **Mauricio Contreras** por su comentario.

Así ha quedado el código:

```
        for(Color i:paleta) {

            if(i.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreColor)) {

                System.out.println("La pocision del color " + i.getNombre() + " es " + paleta.indexOf(i));

            }//FIN DEL IF

        } //FIN DEL FOR
        break;
```

Sin necesidad del contador.